# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 kills cshtml performance in large solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just moved an Asp.Net MVC project into our main solution, straight away the performance in cshtml files is incredibly slow, you can see each character appear after a 1 second delay. Also switching between .cs files also takes 1 second.

- Outside of this solution performance is fine, this solution holds a number of projects which my solution references.
- The problem occurs on 2 machines which have Update 2 present, a machine that doesn't have Update 2 present doesn't get the problem
- Neither my machine nor the others use any plugins

Obviously I have a workaround, just do my coding outside of the main solution but has anyone else experienced this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make it freeze simply by putting a debugger keyword in a ts file, as soon as it hits it it freezes VS for a good minute, there are other problems all seemingly related to .ts files.

I went up to RC3, no change. Uninstalled and went back to VS2013 without any updates and it now works fine

NB RC3 did -not- help it at all

Just to be clear, I have never installed Web Essentials and this is now VS2013 with "microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34790"; installed

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue with performance of some files and found it to be Plugin related.  For my setup the issue was [Web Essentials 2013](http://vswebessentials.com/) needed to updated.

If that doesn't work, try disabling all of your plugins, especially and large ones like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (and Resharper plugins!), restart VS and see if the problems are resolved.  Then renable plugins until you have found the culprit.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use any plugins, I have a Vanilla setup